# nodejs async waterfall use mongoose findOneAndUpdate in the second function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async.js

I want to user async waterfall to upload a file and then return the remote file path and pass it to the second function which is mongoose `findOneAndUpdate` to save the path to user's document.

```
async.waterfall({
    uploadedFile: function (acb) { fileUpload(req, res, acb); },
    user: function (acb) { 
        Users.findOneAndUpdate({ uuid: req.user.uuid }, 
            { $set: {
                file: 'RESULTFROMWATERFALL',
                email: req.body.email,
                name: req.body.name,
    } }).exec(acb); }
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('result: ', data)
});
```

I am stuck with this and don't know how to proceed to get the result from function one and pass it to mongoose find and update function.

If the upload function is used isolated, it works like this:

```
fileUpload(req, res, function(err, result) {
        console.log('i can see result here: ', result) // https//some.remote.path/file.txt
    })
```

could somebody help me fix this `async.waterfall` example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
async.waterfall([
(callback) => {
    fileUpload(req, res, (err,data)=>{
        callback(err, data);
    });
},
(updateURL, callback)=>{
    Users.findOneAndUpdate({ uuid: req.user.uuid },
        { $set: {
                file: 'RESULTFROMWATERFALL',
                email: req.body.email,
                name: req.body.name,
            } }).exec(callback); 
}
}], (err, data) => {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
console.log('result: ', data)
});
```

Comment: the problem is that ` req.body.email` is null. why is that? should we apply something to it?

Comment: do req.body.email null in both function?

Comment: yep it is null in both

Comment: would you show me the code because it seems to be right, there could be some mistake in front end side or console req.body before async.waterfall check email is coming or not, if won't that means it is front end mistake.

Comment: Its all my pleasure to help you.

Comment: give me your email, we can collaborate on some projects if you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166201/discussion-between-radhey-shyam-and-bonnard).

Comment: I need 20 more reputations for discussion, sorry for the late reply due to some urgent family work

Comment: My email is radheyg11@gmail.com